# PhoneApplicationService.Activated after tombstoning?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Windows Phone 8 Silverlight app. I have a custom control on the main XAML page. The control subscribes to the Activated event in its constructor:

```
public MyView()
{
    //...
    PhoneApplicationService.Current.Activated += OnAppActivated;
}


public void OnAppActivated(object o, ActivatedEventArgs a)
{
//...
}
```

My testing on emulator and on a Windows 8.1 device shows that when the app is tombstoned (I use the checkbox on the Debug properties to make sure that happens), the Activated event is **not** delivered when the app is reactivated. The wording of the MSDN docs for the Activated event, however, suggests otherwise:

> It is possible for your application to be activated without having been tombstoned.

And I have crash reports that suggest that the event is occasionally delivered after tombstoning, when all variables are reset.

Is it really possible? How can I reproduce Activate after tombstoning?

EDIT: Application_Activated in the app class does run. Here's a funny data point. In the no-tombstoning scenario, the order of calls upon reactivation is:

- MyView.OnAppActivated
- App.Application_Activated

Meanwhile, in the tombstoned app scenario, the calls go:

- App.Application_Activated
- MyView.MyView

What I'm saying here, when I'm testing, the control constructor always runs **after** the activation notification fires. So the control has no chance to hook the event. That explains the lack of event (despite the docs claiming the contrary).

Now, that's what my testing shows. The docs and crash reports suggest the opposite order - sometimes. When exactly?

Comment: It should be raised - how are you reactivating the app? [Details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff817008(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: Set the "Tombstone on deactivation" flag. Run on simulator. Click the Windows key, then the Back key. The breakpoint in OnAppActivated doesn't fire.

Comment: Notably, Application_Activated in the app class does fire. In the control, not so much.

Comment: Thanks - I missed that it was a custom control. See answer.

Comment: The MSDN quote doesn't imply you will get `Activated` after being tombstoned. It implies the exact opposite (although it is strangely worded, I will request a change).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your control hasn't yet been created by the time the event is raised.

The standard handler is called (as you note in comment above) but none of the constructors for the XAML page (or its children) are run until after this. So you haven't even hooked up the handler when the event is raised.

Comment: My problem is that **sometimes** the Activated handler in the control does run. I can't reproduce it :(

Comment: It will run if you are **not** tombstoned.

Comment: That much I understand and can easily reproduce. The problem is that I have strong evidence that out in the wild, occasionally the event handler runs even if it is.

Comment: What do you mean by variables not being there? Are they fields in your class, or entries in the `State` dictionary?

Comment: A global in a native library, in this particular case. Anyways, I'm going to process this case explicitly, insert a call-home, and release the app into the wild. Then we'll see.